# Datatable style CSS td in table model

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, datatables

I need to style the ds elements inside my table to have padding left and right equal to 0px and nothing I do affects them.

```
 <table class="table table-borderless" style="overflow: scroll" width="100%" id="topAlarmsDeviceLine">
                        </table>
let tableModel = [
        {
            title: '',
            type: 'html',
            targets: 0,
            data: function (source, type, val){
                return source.Denumire;
            }
        },
        {
            title: '',
            type: 'html',
            targets: 1,
            data: function(source, type, val) {
                if (source.processor && source.processor > 59) {
                    return "<td style='padding: 0px !important;'>" + Math.round(source.processor / 60) + 'h' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #F0AD4E; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span></td>";
                } else if(source.processor && 0 < source.processor && source.processor < 60) {
                    return "<td style='padding: 0px !important;'>" + source.processor + 'm' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #F0AD4E; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span></td>";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        },
        {
            title: '',
            type: 'html',
            targets: 2,
            data: function(source, type, val) {
                if (source.ram && source.ram > 59) {
                    return "<td style='padding: 0px !important;'>" + Math.round(source.ram / 60) + 'h' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #5CB85C; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span></td>";
                } else if(source.ram && 0 < source.ram && source.ram < 60) {
                    return "<td style='padding: 0px !important;'>" + source.ram + 'm' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #5CB85C; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span></td>";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        },...
```

I have tried to add the td style in return, the way is is my example, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to select the table td and use css jquery method, still nothing:

$('#topAlarmsDeviceLine td').css('padding', '0px');

Ultimately, I am trying to keep the colored square (the span), in line with the text no matter how long the text is, and I've seen that removing the td padding does it.

Comment: I see no table **rows** anywhere (`<tr>`) – if those are missing, the HTML is invalid, which might cause problems...

Comment: I think the Datatable deals with creating the tr and td elements...initially I had only the span element, I added the td because I wanted to apply css style on them. In the browser inspect I have the tr and and everything.

Answer (score 2):

I can suppose you to set  `!important` after because using `table-borderless` may lead to some default style for the table and its child objects.

Try `$('#topAlarmsDeviceLine td').css('padding', '0px !important');`

You can check computed styles in the Developer's pane and follow the rule that sets your current padding.

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: Can you post ready code in codepen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `data:` option which returns a `<td style="...">foo</td>` string, that means you are trying to insert a `<td>` element into the `<td>` element which is automatically constructed by DataTables.

In such cases, DataTables will remove your `<td>` and only show the inner text.

So, this is what is happening in code such as:

```js
return "<td style='padding: 0px !important;'> + ..."
```

You can try something like this:

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": null,
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "start_date": "2011/01/25",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  },
  {
    "id": "567",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "432",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "id": "987",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'itp', // just for demo simplicity
    data: dataSet,
    columnDefs: [{
        title: 'Position',
        type: 'html',
        targets: 0,
        data: function(source, type, val) {
          return '<td style="background-color: #F0AD4E; padding: 8px; margin: 3px;">' + source.position + '</td>';
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Office',
        type: 'html',
        targets: 1,
        data: function(source, type, val) {
          return '<span style="background-color: #F0AD4E; padding: 8px; margin: 3px;">' + source.office + '</span>';
        }
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example">
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the above demo, the Position column attempts (and fails) to use styles in a `<td>` element; whereas the Office column uses a `<span>` element. You can see the styles are successfully applied to the span.

---

What you can do with this is limited - maybe too limited for your needs. You may need to experiment.

You can take a look at the DataTables [default styling options](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes). Those may also be too limited for your needs.

You can use another styling framework - one of those which is supported by DataTables.  The DataTables download page has a list. See [Step 1. Choose a styling framework](https://datatables.net/download/index).

---

**Update**

I missed one more way to handle cell styling - and maybe this is the most flexible way to style all cells in a specific data column:

Use [`className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className):

```
className: 'my_cell_style'
```

Example:

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "start_date": "2011/01/25",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  },
  {
    "id": "567",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "432",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "id": "987",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'itp', // just for demo simplicity
    data: dataSet,
    columnDefs: [{
        title: 'Position',
        type: 'html',
        targets: 0,
        data: function(source, type, val) {
          return '<td style="background-color: #F0AD4E; padding: 8px; margin: 3px;">' + source.position + '</td>';
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Office',
        type: 'html',
        targets: 1,
        data: function(source, type, val) {
          return '<span style="background-color: #F0AD4E; padding: 8px; margin: 3px;">' + source.office + '</span>';
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'html',
        targets: 2,
        data: "name",
        className: 'my_cell_style'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```css
td.my_cell_style {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #2f8d46;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example">
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note the use of `td` in the style definition `td.my_cell_style` to avoid also styling the heading cell.

The `<td>` tags generated by DataTables look like this:

```
<td class=" cell_style">Airi Satou</td>
```

I think this last option is already described in other questions but I haven't found a good example. I will update here if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I added css style white-space:nowrap; on the table div parent:

```
<div class="panel-body" style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; white-space:nowrap; scrollbar-width: thin;">
                    *some other span elem with infos*
                    <table class="table table-borderless" style="overflow: scroll" width="100%" id="topAlarmsDeviceLine">
                    </table>
                </div>
```

But I haven't found a way to style the td s generated from datatable.